# What kind of Neural Networks are required for Diffusion models?

Tags: neural-networks, generative-models, diffusion

It appears that regular feed-forward and convolutions are not enough to make diffusion models work (from some personal limited testing, they do not work at all). The typical infrastructure was a U-Net and now Transformer Models seems like they are taking over as well.

I understand the analogies for a residual network in the "regression" settings, and transformer abilities in the context of language models - but I do not understand what is the minimal capacity of a network to memorize the diffusion gradients. In other words, what would be the minimal requirement say for an example of a small diffusion model with `mnist` dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very new to the diffusion model community, so take my answer with a grain of salt. But let me attempt to answer your question in a more general sense.

**TL;DR**: These models perform better. I'm sure they have tried other architectures, and you could use simpler architectures, but you probably wouldn't be able to get far with them or obtain clean results and state-of-the-art scores.

Regarding **transformer abilities**, in several ML applications, you can find the use of attention-based architectures (from regression to computer vision and NLP). For example, recently, I have been working with one-dimensional regression functions and we have found an architecture that utilizes the attention heads: transformer abilities just improve its performance, so why not use it?

Regarding **residual networks**, I think the answer here is a bit more clear. Although you don't have to use them, the residual methodology is used to perform the following:

1. the (encoded) temporal information can easily be passed to the architecture
2. for conditional diffusion models, the class information can also be easily passed

Both are passed just by adding (encoded) information to decided layers in the architecture (I suggest watching the following [great tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBCRlnwJtZU&ab_channel=Outlier), particularly the part on classifier free guidance (min 17:00).

Finally, to convince yourself, you could check the following coding tutorial, such as:

- [Weights & Biases](https://wandb.ai/capecape/train_sd/reports/How-To-Train-a-Conditional-Diffusion-Model-From-Scratch--VmlldzoyNzIzNTQ1) tutorial where you can see directly that both temporal and class information are added (kind of) as a form of residual connection

[image]

So to conclude, although these models have the desired effect and ease implementations (e.g, incorporation of temporal information, adding class-specific information), you could test other architectures, but for complicated tasks, even on the mnist dataset, I doubt that you could get good performance.